# MATCH_PARENT inside WRAP_CONTENT is giving me problems

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a bar in the bottom of my layout which consists in a horizontal `LinearLayout` (like a row) that contains vertical `LinearLayout`s (Like a cell of a row).

The Horizontal linearLayout (row) haves `WRAP_CONTENT` height because i want the bar fit its elements height, and the vertical linear layouts (cells) have `MATCH_PARENT` because they can have for example a item centered vertically inside,
so they are `MATCH_PARENT` and they must have the Height of the higher height of the cells on the row.

The problem is that the bar is occupying all the height of my screen. I think that there are problems with `MATCH_PARENT` inside a `WRAP_CONTENT`.
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: can u please share your layout code here?

Answer (score 0):

To set `MATCH_PARENT` height to `LinearLayouts`(cells) you must have to fix some height of row(`LinearLayout`) otherwise it will covers entire screen